# Flow complains about type incompatibility even though I check type first

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have written a React dropdown component which I can supply either of the following to :

- An array of `string`s
- An array of simple JSON object each of which contains two properties of `text` and `icon`.

My simple flow types look as follows:

`type DropdownMenuItemType = DropdownMenuIconAndTextType | string;`

```
type DropdownMenuIconAndTextType ={
    text: string,
    icon?: React$Element<React$ElementType>;
}
```

Previous versions of the component only supports strings. The addition of an element to support `text` and an `icon` is a new feature request which I am in the process of implementing. I don't want any breaking changes for my existing users.

Therefore within my component I try to attempt to convert any `string` supplied and wrap it in a `DropdownMenuIconAndTextType` so everything ends up as this type. Items that are already `DropdownMenuIconAndTextType` just remain so.

```
let Array<DropdownMenuItemType> originalItems = 
let Array<DropdownMenuIconAndTextType> convertedItems = [];
{'English', 'French', 'German', {text: 'Dutch', icon : <SomeIcon />}};
     items.forEach( (currItem: DropdownMenuItemType) => {
           if(typeof currItem === DropdownMenuIconAndTextType){
               convertedItems.push(currItem);
           }
           else {
               convertedItems.push({text: currItem.toString()});
           }

});
```

However flow has one error with :

```
  if(typeof currItem === DropdownMenuIconAndTextType){
               convertedItems.push(currItem);
  }
```

and it says that `currItem` could still be a `string` and is incompatible with `convertedItems` despite it being type checked as `DropdownMenuIconAndTextType`.

What do I need to do to satisfy flow in this scenario ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're mixing up the distinction between Flow's type code and JS code.

Inside of type signatures, `typeof` returns the type of a literal value, as described [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/). In the JS code that exists at runtime, such as in your `if` statement, `typeof` will just tell you whether something is a string, object, etc., as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). So the left side of your conditional operator will evaluate to either `"string"`, or `"object"`, not to the actual Flow type of the variable.

On the right side of your conditional, you have the Flow type `DropdownMenuIconAndTextType`, which only exists at type-checking time, not at runtime. I'm kind of surprised that Flow doesn't give you an error because of that.

Try something like this:

```js
  if(typeof currItem !== 'string'){
               convertedItems.push(currItem);
  }
```

This will check whether the value that exists at runtime is a string or an object, which should work with Flow's type refinements.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense. Much appreciated.